# Safe level of chlorine in water

Tags: human-biology, food, hair

Chlorine is usually mixed in water to make it safe for consumption. What is a safe quantity of chlorine that can be consumed? What are the side effects of chlorine and does this include hair loss? <del>What are some common chemicals utilized for water purification?</del> Thank you.

Comment: What has this got to do with governments?

Comment: You are asking many questions here. Q1 is in any case off-topic. Question 5 is too broad.

Answer (score 1):

Chlorine is a reactive substance and an oxidizing agent. It can cause damage to surfaces exposed to it such as eyes, skin etc but it cannot penetrate deeper. Chlorine can damage your hair by oxidation — hair becomes rough and brittle. This is not same as hair loss — chlorine doesn't cause hair to fall out because it cannot penetrate to the follicles. See [here](http://www.hairdr.com/news/press-releases/dr-robert-leonard-exposes-the-truths-and-myths-surrounding-hair-loss-in-men-and-women/)

[EPA](http://water.epa.gov/drink/contaminants/basicinformation/disinfectants.cfm) has set maximum residual disinfectant level for chlorine (as Cl<sub>2</sub> and other chlorinating agents such as chloramine [NH<sub>2</sub>Cl] and chlorine dioxide [Cl<sub>2</sub>O]) beyond which it is considered unsafe.

```
Chloramine       :  4.0 mg/L or 4 ppm
Chlorine         :  4.0 mg/L or 4 ppm
Chlorine Dioxide :  0.8 mg/L or 800 ppb
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I mentioned "govt", as different countries have different standards.